# Restart execution of file from error handler after rectifying errors in nodejs

Tags: node.js, error-handling, process, event-handling

1. If I have 10 lines of code and I get an error on line 3 can I restart execution after rectifying errors or restart execution from line 3 from the same context left at line 2?
2. I am sure this is a very common use case or I may just be asking a stupid question I should avoiding. Any help?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Invalid_assignment_left-hand_side

```
let x = {};
x.test = 10;
x?.tester = 20;
console.log(x.tester);

process.on('SyntaxError', err => {
  console.log(`Uncaught Exception: ${err.message}`)
  console.error(e instanceof SyntaxError);
  process.exit(1) // restart execution of code from here instead
})
```